# Can I check in unix binaries (compiled executable, libraries, etc) into PVCS

Tags: unix, version-control

We are starting up a Unix development engagement and evaluating version control options.

Specific question: Does PVCS deployed on a Unix platform support checking in compiled code from a Unix build environment?

If so, example command perhaps?

Not looking to hear about other SCM systems at this point.

Comment: Why wouldn't it support that? But also, **DO NOT USE PVCS**.

Comment: Jace... that is not an answer, it is a question and an assertion.

Comment: Why would you want to do that — check-in derived objects?  And if you're evaluating version control options, why don't you want to hear about other SCM systems?

Comment: Actually, Jace's contribution is a comment, the same as mine is a comment.  If it was an answer, you'd probably be correct, but comments are not answers.

Comment: OMG... A) Because it is something the client wants and B) Because I am asking about PVCS.

Comment: When you ask about bad practices (whether in choice of SCM or methods of using it), expect to get pushback from people who think that bad practices should be discouraged. I don't have a view on PVCS — I used it briefly, once, and wasn't sufficiently immersed in it to form a view on its capabilities.  I don't think checking in binaries is a good idea — but stating that the customer is mandating both PVCS and checking-in binaries will help head off the redirections.

Comment: I didn't ask about bad practices. SCM is the underpinning of content management, is it bad practice to version manage images? I don't think so.

Comment: It's not bad practice to manage versions of images. But there are probably systems better-suited to managing those than a system designed to manage text files will be.

Comment: Can a locking-based VCS support modern software development in any fashion?  How are the build scripts or project files managed - or does the team take it in turns to commit new files in a round-robin fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that PVCS would distinguish between binary and text files. Even if it did, it should support the notion of a binary file.

PVCS apparently doesn't do merging (not as a built-in operation), so there really isn't much that it needs to do to "support" checking in of unix binaries.

You may have problems dealing with the file permissions, however I would consider that to be a security feature - the files shouldn't be marked as executable unless you intend them to be executed, a deploy script would more than achieve this.

That said.  Semantically, it is problematic asking if it "supports" checking in of unix binaries: Can a system that happens to allow such files to be checked in be claimed to "support" those files if it provides no features that ease management of those specific files, as distinct from other types of files?

Unfortunately their website is so full of marketing information that it is next to impossible to find out this information.  Seriously pick a different VCS if at all possible. Heck, even Perforce would be a better choice, they provide tools for almost every current operating system and provide many levels of documentation.  (Personally, I'm inclined to recommend Git, although Perforce would be a better choice in this case if you are more interested in versioning many binary files)